# URI routing in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

As the title suggests, my issue is with codeIgniter.

I have used a code in an .htaccess file  to remove index.php which works all OK.

But I need to go further in changing the URI:

My main controller is **page()**, so when a user is in my homepage, the URL-bar shows:

```
www.example.com/page/
```

(because homepage is index page, it does not show the page name as usual the controller suffice),

but If I go to registration page, the URL-bar shows:

```
www.example.com/page/register
```

Up to here everything is OK, but I want the codeIgniter to show my domain without the **page()** when the user is in my homepage, I don't want foolish `www.example.com/page/` to appear and I think when someone is visiting index page, the URL-bar better to be `www.example.com`

Comment: When you enter `www.example.com`, redirecting to `/page`?

Comment: No, it does not redirect, it is just the controller that must load the view. When you go directly to www.example.com, it is ok, but when within the site you click on a link to homepage, it goes to homepage, but this time in the URL-bar, a /page/ is added

Comment: Use `<?php echo base_url(); ?>` for homepage link

Comment: not a good suggestion. I need routing methods

Answer (score 3):

You can define a custom route in config/routes.php - for example:

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'page';
```

Then, `http://example.com`

goes to `http://example.com/page`

then if you did not specify any data , it will route to default controller.

Answer (score 1):

for the link to register:

```
  www.example.com/register
```

in config/routes.php

```
 $route['register'] = 'page/register';
```

Answer (score 0):

You have everything explained here in great detail.

http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/tutorial/static_pages.html  there is an example here on the bottom how to do uri routing with routes.php file in codeigniter.